# How do I zoom in a GridLayout view group centered at the focus point where multi-touch takes place?

Tags: android

For study purpose I am trying to write an Android app that can load pictures in any size (e.g. 8000x8000px). To do so I have to preprocess a picture into smaller pieces and load only the pieces that need to be displayed into the cells of a GridLayout view group.

I am able follow the instruction and make this view scroll (i.e. panning). Now I am trying to add zooming to this GridLayout view, but it doesn't seem to be as straightforward. Basically the view keeps shrink to (0, 0) instead of the focus point where multi-touch happens. The zooning behavior I need is something like Google Map. However my implementation does not really work. It always zoom to the upper left conner (0,0), because for zoom in/out, only the size scale is changed.

My code looks like

```
    private final class onScaleListener implements OnScaleListener {

    @Override
    public void onScale(float scaleFactor, float focusX, float focusY)
    {            
        for (int x = 0; x < GRID_DENSITY; x++)
        {
            Spec columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(x); 
            for (int y = 0; y < GRID_DENSITY; y++)
            {
                Spec rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(y);

                LayoutParams l = new LayoutParams(rowSpec, columnSpec);
                l.height = (int) (_gridHeight * scaleFactor);
                l.width = (int) (_gridWidth * scaleFactor);

                _gridLayout.updateViewLayout(_imageViewMatrix[x][y], l);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector arg0)
{
    _scaleFactor *= _scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor();

    // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
    _scaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(_scaleFactor, 5.0f));

    _onScaleListener.onScale(_scaleFactor, _scaleGestureDetector.getFocusX(), _scaleGestureDetector.getFocusY());

    return true;
}
```

Thanks!